# Being a postdoc in Canberra

Tags: postdocs, australia

I have worked in a top public university in the US collaborating with well-known people and have been contemplating applying to Australian National University Canberra for another postdoc. I am an international person and will be on visa. Wanted to learn from people how life could be different (better/worse) with postdoc salaries and benefits in Australia (e.g., medical expenses, which feels scary in the US). I have a dependent partner who is also skilled to find a job. Would also love to know about societal acceptance of international people in and around Canberra.

Comment: From the folks I’ve known from ANU, Canberra (and Australia in general) are quite welcoming.

Answer (score 2):

Australia is a multi-cultural country.  Sure, there are idiots here and there, but the majority of the population is very sensitive towards diversity, especially universities.  You will find people speaking up instead of brushing it off.

As for medical, it is far cry from the USA. You can look this up.  You can also look up the premium you'll be paying; a family of four cover is around $300-$350 AUD per month.

My only complains about Canberra: too quiet and cold during winter.

Answer (score 0):

The ANU is (arguably) the highest ranked university in Australia and consistent ranks within the top 50 universities in the world (roughly commensurate with universities like NYU or the Sorbonne).  (See discussion in comments below on ranking systems.)  It is an elite research university and is a nice place to study and work.  The ANU has an extremely successful research record including many world-class research groups and hubs, and consistent success in attracting grant funding and producing research output.  It also has a substantial cohort of international students and is a highly attractive study destination for students from China and other Asian countries (mostly because it is geographically closer than elite universities in Europe and the US).

Canberra is the hub of the federal government in Australia and it is a highly educated and affluent population (probably somewhat similar to the central parts of Washington DC, but at lower scale).  It is a comfortable place to live and work, though perhaps somewhat expensive relative to some other cities.  The city has a substantial proportion of non-white migrants and is only slightly less multicultural than major Western metropolises like London.  Migrants make up about 28% of the Canberra population (see this [relevant news article](https://www.canberratimes.com.au/story/6004901/migrants-are-moving-to-canberra-in-record-numbers/)) and within the central areas near the city and the ANU the proportion would be higher again (since many of the outer suburban areas of the city are less multicultural than the mean).  Canberra has a substantial population of migrants from England, China, India, the Phillipines, Vietnam, Sri Lanka, and many other countries.  No-one will bat an eyelid at a non-white migrant living in the city or working at ANU; it is so common as to be banal.

You can find information on the academic salary scale at ANU [here](https://services.anu.edu.au/human-resources/enterprise-agreement/schedule-1-academic-staff-salary-schedule-0) (note that the unit of measurement in this schedule is $AUD, not $US).  Postdocs are typically Level A appointments, but I'm sure the position description for the position you are contemplating specifies this.  You can find information on health coverage for temporary visa holders in Australia from the [Department of Home Affairs](https://immi.homeaffairs.gov.au/help-support/meeting-our-requirements/health/adequate-health-insurance) (which is based in Canberra).  Broadly speaking, migrants on a temporary visa are not eligible for Medicare coverage.  Most major health insurers in Australia have policies for [healthcare coverage for overseas students](https://www.medibank.com.au/overseas-health-insurance/guides/articles/which-health-cover-for-my-visa/) and my (vague) understanding is that this is quite a bit less expensive and scary than in the US.

*Full Disclosure: I am an alumnus of the ANU and have also worked there as a researcher.*

Comment: "The ANU is the highest ranked university in Australia" -- depends on the ranking system.  Further, it is depends on the subject and discipline.

Comment: I refer here to the overall ranking in standard research assessments, not rankings of specific subjects or disciplines.  While there is some variation between ranking systems (and occasionally the University of Melbourne comes out on top), my observation has been that the ANU is ranked highest in a fairly consistent manner throughout most standard ranking systems that focus on research.

Comment: @VitaminE: I have edited the answer to now say that the ANU is *arguably* the highest ranked, and directed readers to this comment section for discussion.

Comment: For what it's worth, US News and World Report ranks ANU as number 6 in Australia, while "The Times" Higher Education ranks it as number 5. This is consistent with my view of ANU as a research mathematician.

Comment: Interesting.  QS puts it at number 1, and I recall it being ranked number 1 in many previous years (though again, that is an overall ranking, not one for a specific discipline).